# Winforms: Correct way to avoid executing code or force to exit methods

Tags: c#, winforms, exit

I often work with Winforms, but I've never really found a "globally accepted" way to exit methods or so.

So, an approach I know it's working for sure it's branching every bit of code I want to check/stop within a if(error).

```
bool error = false;
if (!error)
{
    //do stuff
}

if(!error)
{
    //do stuff
}

error = true;

if (!error)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Then there are other two ways but I don't know exactly if they lead to unexpected behaviours.

The application.exit() one:

```
bool error = false;
        if (error)
        {
            Application.exit();
        }

        //do stuff
        //code code code

        if (error)
        {
            Application.exit();
        }

        //do stuff
        //code code code
        error = true;

        if (error)
        {
            Application.exit();
        }

        //THIS CODE SHOULD NOT EXECUTE???? But i think it actually does...
//From what I understood it keep executing all the code in the method and     then exits (message pumps and so on)
        //do stuff
        //code code code
```

And then the Environment.exit(int) approach

```
 bool error = false;
        if (error)
        {
            Environment.exit();
        }

        //do stuff
        //code code code

        if (error)
        {
            Environment.exit();
        }

        //do stuff
        //code code code
        error = true;

        if (error)
        {
            Environment.exit(1);
        }

        //THIS CODE SHOULD NOT EXECUTE BECAUSE Environment.exit(int) actually             breaks the application with an exception
        //Works but bad practice
        //do stuff
        //code code code
```

Advices? Best Practices? Corrections?

Anything is welcome

Comment: Why don't you use try/catch blocks? Also what do you want to accomplish? Do you only want to quit the method and keep the application running, or actually make the application "crash" by shutting it down?

Comment: `Environment.Exit` doesn't breaks the application with exception. It rather terminates it forcefully.

Comment: what about `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();`?

Comment: That said,you could refactor your code, and make all the steps as interface or delegate, and loop through the steps, then a single method which throws if there is an error.

Comment: @HW I'm not catching an exception, no real error are present. I'm just checking a condition In which i want some code to not be executed.

dotctor, I must try that. I don't know. Btw your advice it's like the first if(error) approach, just using delegates instead of the if. No good

Answer (score 0):

> The [return](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/1h3swy84.aspx) statement terminates execution of the method in which it appears and returns control to the calling method.

From your initial post and your description in the comments, this is what you are looking for? So basically use something like the following and handle the return values differently (returning 0 usually indicates that everything went allright while -1 and possibly other integers represent different error types. Of course you can instead use boolean if you only need to check if the method performed properly or not, or even define your own exceptions).

```
public int TestMethod(){
    //do stuff
    if (badStuffHappened)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    // Do more stuff which is not executed, 
    // if badStuffHappened before you reach the previous if statement.
    return 0;
}
```